# Trying to refresh/show beginning div within a modal

Tags: jquery

So here's where I'm stuck at (suck at jQuery). Within in a modal window (Bootstrap), I have a button that when clicked will fade out and then show a hidden div. Now when you close that modal window, I want the button to show. However, currently I'm stuck at the text always showing until I refresh the page. Just not sure how to show the button.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <button class="btn-profile" type="button">Show Profile</button>
    <div class="profile">
        Your Profile
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.profile').hide();

$('.btn-profile').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.profile').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.btn-profile').hide();
});
```

Comment: To understand, Do you want the .btn-profile to show up whenever you close the modal window? 
Is the button inside the modal? 
Can you show some of your markup?

Comment: Yes, the button is inside of the modal body. So, whenever you click the button ".profile" will show. And when you close the modal and reopen it, ".btn-profile" will show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the button properties when the modal windows is shown.  For this you should use the event that is triggered from Boostrap

```
$('#yourModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $('.profile').hide();
   $('.btn-profile').show();
});
```

See Event section of: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Comment: Awesome! This was what I was looking. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. Thank you!